# iFrame for Flutter Web, iOS & Android App

Tags: android, ios, flutter, iframe

I want to integrate some iFrames from multiple sources (not only YouTube) for my Flutter Web, Android & IOS App but I didn't succeed.

I searched on pub.dev if there is a package I can use for the 3 platforms, I didn't find it.
So I use WebView for Android & IOS but I don't know what to do for Web.
I tried to use "IFrameElement class" but I didn't succeed... (I'm not very good...)

1. Do you know a miracle package I can use?
2. Otherwise what do you recommend (multiple packages, just WebView and IFrameElement, something else...)?
3. Can you help me with my code below?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ShowIframe extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowIframe({
    Key? key,
    required this.link,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String link;

  @override
  State<ShowIframe> createState() => _ShowIframeState();
}

class _ShowIframeState extends State<ShowIframe> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Iframe on Flutter Web'),
        ),
        body: , // I don't know
      );
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Iframe on Flutter Android & IOS'),
        ),
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: widget.link,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

For "link" if I have this iFrame :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yRlwOdCK7Ho" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I use "https://www.youtube.com/embed/yRlwOdCK7Ho"

Maybe there is another way to use the entire iFrame code...

Answer (score 0):

For iframes in flutter, we use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview it works the most consistently and injecting javascript is generally pretty easy. I can provide some code if needed

Comment: Thank you, I already tried the beta version for web but, for now, I don't understand how it works, I mean, a simple way to make it work. I tried to read the example but I'm not good enough to truly understand it. Is there a very simple way like juste calling InAppWebView(initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri('https://flutter.dev'),),), for example, like WebView